# Win 10 optional update keeps returning

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have this optional update returning, even though I've installed it several times successfully (i.e. without error or other complaint), it returns within hours.
It's not a general update problem because other drivers from the optional list have been installed successfully.

I've searched online but either lack the correct search string or there's not much info online. Would like a solution to fix this without completely disabling these types of updates.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't it surprise me that this is for an HP printer. Their drivers are absolute tosh. Have you done a manual install of the full HP suite from the HP website?

Comment: You can just Hide Optional Driver Update in Windows Update. That Null Driver update is on my system. I just hide then and it does not re-introduce itself as a driver to be updated.

Comment: How do I just install the printer driver and not all the crap that comes with the HP driver?
Even the "basic driver" package is 24MB and contains stuff like scanner which I don't need or want.
I extracted the package, right-clicked on the *.inf files, installed them but this optional driver still keeps coming back and bugs the hell out of me.